# How can I comfort my dog when he is dry heaving and obsessively trying to eat leaves?

Tags: dogs

A couple weeks ago, my dog had an episode where he was dry-heaving for a few hours. When I let him outside he obsessively and frenetically looked for certain types of dried leaves to eat (note that he couldn't eat any grass because the ground was covered with snow).

About halfway through the episode, my dog succeeded in vomiting, but it didn't stop the dry-heaving nor the obsession with eating leaves.  Eventually the episode passed and he calmed down, and there were no more symptoms.

This has now started up again.

Is there anything I can do to ease his anxiety and help him vomit when he can't find grass in the winter time?  Does letting him out to eat grass/leaves help the vomit come sooner? After he vomits, is there anything I can do to help the dry-heaving stop sooner?

Comment: Vet. Now. Your dog is telling you something is very wrong.

Comment: Can you think of something unique that ate both times?

Comment: My vet's advise was to only bring him in if he threw up again, which he didn't.  He calmed down after a few hours again, but this time kept heaving throughout the night.  By morning he was only heaving every five minutes or so and it eventually stopped.

Comment: @Frisbee, I've been trying to think of unique things he ate, but haven't come up with anything.

Comment: Was it vomit vomit, food filled goop, or was it bile vomit, bright yellow? The latter is really not so good. Our dog had similar when he went off dry food. Is your dog still eating and pooping ok as well?

Comment: yeah, it was vomit vomit. Eating, energy, and stool were all normal.